# How to convert String Jul 21, 2020, 7:53:14 PM into "DD/MM/YYYY a" format in java

Tags: java, date

I have a string as **"Jul 22, 2020, 11:56:51 PM"** and I want to convert it into **"DD/MM/YYYY a"** format so that the output is **22/07/2020 11:56:51 PM**.

I have tried but it gives me a time difference of 5:30 hours. I want to have the same date.

> `ExportObj`  has a property `date` which is of type `String`.

Output I'm getting is - 07/22/2020 06:26 PM

```
public Class Export {

public static void main(string[] args){
        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(user.getDateFormatWithTime());
        String id = String.valueOf(currentUser.getTimeZoneId());
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
        sf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
        ExportObj obj = new ExportObj();
        obj.setDate(sf.format(new Date()));
        System.out.println(obj.getDate());
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled. I should have liked to try it out to see what happens and analyse why.

Comment: Also I would suggest using yyyy instead of YYYY because yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar

Answer (score 1):

You should not keep date and time as a `String` in your `ExportObj`. Just as you keep numbers in `int` and `double` variables and Boolean values in `boolean` variables (I hope), use proper date-time types for your dates and times. In this case a `ZonedDateTime` is probably best suited, but depending on circumstances and precise requirements you may consider `Instant` or some other class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

When you need to show the date and time to a user, format the date-time into an appropriate string for that purpose.

### java.time

Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. For your conversion:

```
    DateTimeFormatter sourceFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, uuuu, hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateTimeFormatter targetormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    String id = "Etc/UTC";
    String stringWeveGot = "Jul 22, 2020, 11:56:51 PM";
    
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(id);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringWeveGot, sourceFormatter)
            .atZone(zone);
    
    System.out.println(dateTime);
    
    String convertedString = dateTime.format(targetormatter);
    
    System.out.println(convertedString);
```

Output:

> ```
> 2020-07-22T23:56:51Z[Etc/UTC]
> 22/07/2020 11:56:51 PM
> ```

As I said, put the `ZonedDateTime` object into your `ExportObj` object, not the string.

### What went wrong in your code?

It’s a bit hard for me to be sure what happened when you got a time that was 5 hours 30 minutes too early since your code isn’t complete and I cannot run it. You probably applied your time zone to only one of your formatters, leaving the other one to use a different time zone, for example the default time zone of your JVM, giving rise to an unwanted conversion between those time zones. `ZonedDateTime` of java.time makes this situation easier to handle since contrary to the old-fashioned `Date` class it keeps the time zone inside the date-time object rather than in the formatters.

### Link

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

**Run this :**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws ParseException {

        
        final String OLD_FORMAT = "MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a";
        final String NEW_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";

        String oldDateString = "Jul 22, 2020, 11:56:51 PM";
        String newDateString;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
        Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
        sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
        newDateString = sdf.format(d);
        System.out.println(newDateString);
        
    }
```

**Output** :

```
22/07/2020 11:56:51 PM
```